# Is there a Wi-Fi-only mode?

Tags: wi-fi

Once I am connected to a Wi-Fi network (regardless of my other connections to 3G and 4G) is there any way to guarantee that all my data goes through Wi-Fi?

Comment: The first part of your question is covered by [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/what-does-it-mean-when-the-connectivity-icons-in-the-status-bar-go-white-in-ginge/9643#9643).  I'm going to edit this to have only the second question -- in the future please ask separate questions separately :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure one if the automation apps, Tasker, Locale, or AutomateIT can do this. Just set it up to disable 3G when connecting to Wi-Fi, and then you can reenable it manually when you're finished with Wifi.

Answer (score 5):

Your phone will default to WiFi when it's available.  If you're paranoid you can disable data while using WiFi but it's not necessary.  I'm not sure how to do it on the Bionic but you could see if it's in the menu that pops up when you hold the power button for a couple seconds or something like unchecking **Use packet data** in `Settings -> Wireless and network -> Mobile networks`.

Comment: Thanks @Mathew, but my Droid Bionic doesn't seem to have that option.

Comment: You have to be careful because if you let mobile data anabled, you phone will probably switch back to that mode when the screen is off and wifi connection is "resting".

Comment: @Balder Good point. I have mine set to never turn off but it would still be an issue if the connection to the network was spotty.

Answer (score 5):

Though @Matthew [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/13613/16265) is correct that a phone will default to Wi-Fi when it is available, that doesn't always ease the mind.

Something you can do to allay your concern is switch the phone into Airplane Mode. This will disable the cell signal and hence all data travelling through your carrier. However, it does not disable Wi-Fi.

[Here's a link on how to do it on the Droid Bionic:](http://www.fanofandroid.com/2011/09/how-to-turn-on-airplane-mode-motorola.html)

> From the main screen, press your Power Button (located on top)
>   Select Airplane Mode to disable mobile network signal

Of course, you won't be able to receive any calls, and this might not be what you want, but it will certainly allay your concerns of using data.

Comment: Good thought.  On my Vibrant airplane mode does disable WiFi initially but you can turn it back on without turning off airplane mode -- does the Bionic work the same way or is WiFi completely untouched?

Comment: I don't have a Droid Bionic but according to the article I linked to, the WiFi is untouched by the airplane mode. It is that way on my HTC Glacier.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a mobile data monitor/manager like [Onavo Count | Monitor Data](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5vbmF2by5hbmRyb2lkLm9uYXZvaWQiXQ..). You can block certain applications from using mobile.

Alternatively, [avast! Mobile Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hdmFzdC5hbmRyb2lkLm1vYmlsZXNlY3VyaXR5Il0.) has a firewall module that allows for application specific data control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All you have to do is:

**1)** Enable Airplane Mode
**2)** Now enable WIFI

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Wireless & Networks > Mobile networks and uncheck the box that says "Data enabled" to disable 3G, 4G etc.