# Disable all non-Wi-Fi Internet connections

Tags: wi-fi, internet

I want my phone (running Android 2.3.5) to only connect to the Internet via Wi-Fi.

How can I disable all non-Wi-Fi connections, such as 3G or similar?

Comment: Duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13610/is-there-a-wi-fi-only-mode/29239#29239

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This functionality is built into android so there's no need for an external tool/application.

In settings:

```
Wireless and networks -> Mobile Networks -> Data Enabled
```

Disable this and you're all set.

Comment: I don't have this option on my Droid Bionic  running system 5.9.902.XT875.Verizon.en.US and Android version 2.3.4.

Comment: @Gdalya here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22906/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-droid-bionic/22907#22907

Answer (score 1):

You can go on the configurations and disable the usage of mobile networks manually. If you want a more handy tool (i.e. not need to open menus), looks like this app can do it: [APN Switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.blinkenlights.android.apnswitch)

> APN-Switch is a simple widget that allows you to quickly enable (or disable) your data connection (3G/EDGE/GPRS) with a single click.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before is to turn on Airplane Mode, then turn on Wifi. Works like a charm on my Galaxy S.

Comment: That would disable normal cell phone functionality too, like calling and texts.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question then!