# How to disable mobile data on DROID Bionic?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-droid-bionic

I tried [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22838/disable-all-non-wi-fi-internet-connections/22840), but there's no such option. I suspect that it might be because of Motorola's customizations.

The device is a DROID Bionic.
System version: 5.9.902.XT875.Verizon.en.US
Android version: 2.3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Verizon](http://support.verizonwireless.com/clc/devices/knowledge_base.html?id=46958):

1. Open settings.
2. Select Battery & data manager.
3. Select Data delivery.
4. Select Data enabled to enable / disable.

Comment: What were they thinking?  I can't imagine why this wouldn't be under Wireless & Networks.

Comment: @TomG I can :) We're used to Android but this is the **droid**! It should be more droid-y! I mean how else would they keep their customers? They have to make other phones look too different to learn so *once you droid you never go back* :) Honestly I have no idea who in their mind does some of the modifications. They must be rerarted or something.