# What is the difference between "Screen On" and "Awake"?

Tags: battery

I can possibly understand why the phone can be Awake without having the screen on (background stuff), but how can the screen be on without it being awake?

[image: Battery usage screen-shot]

<sup>If relevant my device is the [Nexus 4](http://www.google.com/nexus/4/) running Android Jelly Bean 4.3.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your screenshot you can find explained (partly) in my answer to [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575). But more specifically to your question, here's what it is about:

- Network signal: Quality of the signal (colors are explained in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38160/16575))
- GPS on: Whether GPS was *actively used*
- Awake: some app requested a *Wakelock* (see: [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/34969/16575)). At least that's the best logical explanation to your question, though I cannot name a reference for that.
- Screen on: the screen was turned on (either manually by the user, or automatically by an app). If the user turns the screen on, that doesn't necessarily mean a wake lock being aquired.
- Charging: a charger was connected and supplied the device with energy