# Meaning of lines in Charging History details view in 4.2.2 Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, gps

In 4.2.2 Jelly Bean when one goes to **Settings -> Battery Use** and tap the graph at the top can find the History details of the charging/discharging of the battery. There are some other historical data below the diagram:  - **Mobile network signal** [was cleared](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20053/whats-the-meaning-of-signal-strength-colors-in-battery-usage-screens)  - **Charging** seems to be clear (green when charged, black when discharged)  - **Screen on** is also OK (blue when lit on, black otherwise)  - **Wi-Fi** may be similarly indicates the On/Off state of the function  - **Awake** is a mistery for me I can not see any correlation between the graph and the On/Off state of the phone  - Finally What does the **GPS on** line exactly indicate?
I have some GPS problem and try to report it. I need to know whether this line indicates the On/Off state of the GPS module or the positioned/lost position state. On my screen it is almost totally black however the module was switched on a day before. There are two or three momentary blue ticks. What do they indicate anyway?

Comment: posting a screen shot may help

Comment: I know. I have the screenshot but how to post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling GPS and using GPS are two different things, when you enable the use of GPS on the menu/toggle, you are just allowing the use of GPS, that dose no mean you acutely using it, when you see in the graph the little blue lines, that means that some application tried/used the GPS and get the exact location (e.g google now).

starting with Android 4.4 you can check which application used the GPS and when under the App permission menu.

Answer (score 1):

When the screen is off and no apps are running in the background (e.g. to check email), your device goes into a low-power state called *sleep*. In this mode, the CPU runs more slowly (or maybe the main CPU is turned off and a smaller, more efficient one takes over) to save power.

The **Awake** line in the battery chart shows when the device is not asleep: that is, it shows blue when the screen is on or when an app is running in the background. Depending on what kind of background apps you use, you might see brief ticks every 15 minutes or every hour, where the device woke up to perform some scheduled task. If there are long blue segments even when the screen is off, then some buggy app is keeping your device awake. You can investigate which with a tool such as Greenify or Wakelock Detector, and if an app is keeping the device awake, you should report this to the developer.

The **GPS on** line indicates when the GPS receiver is powered on. This happens whenever an app requests a precise location, and it'll show blue regardless of whether the GPS receiver has calculated a position or not. A brief tick means the GPS was turned on and then turned off as soon as it calculated a position. This is used by Google Play Services' geofencing functionality, by Google Location Sharing, Google Now, and other similar apps that don't track you all the time but want to *sample* your location occasionally.