# Battery usage screen: where did signal strength details go to with Oreo?

Tags: battery-history

In 2012, we had the question on [What's the meaning of signal strength colors in battery usage screens?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20053/16575). Now, with Oreo, I can no longer find those details on my device: tapping on the graph no longer reveals them. Have they be removed – or am I just (color) blind and missed something? How to show them in Oreo?

<sub>(in case it matters: I'm using LOS 15.1 / Android 8.1)</sub>

Comment: I think this was the case with Nougat too, though I am not fully sure.

Comment: Nope. In Nougat they still can be reached by tapping the usage graph (just checked on LOS 14.1 / Android 7.1; my BQ still has no Oreo available). I've tried multiple web searches already, but nothing turned up; maybe I didn't have the correct search terms; the screen was called "history details", or in German "Verlaufsdetails").

Comment: I've seen people recommend [GSam Battery monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm) as an alternative. Requires ADB I think for some stats.

Comment: Thanks @SSS. Though the primary goal of my question is to find where the setting might be hidden, 3rd party solutions might serve as a last resort. I'll never understand why such useful features should be removed in the first place…