# Why are my network icons blue?

Tags: notification-bar

I've got a Motorola Electrify on Android 2.3. Sometimes my network icons (3G and the cellular network bars) are grey, and sometimes they're blue. They seem to be blue when I have a good connection and/or when my connection will work.

What exactly do the colors mean? I've noticed when I have a grey 3G icon, my wireless tether doesn't work at all and I often can't get web pages to load right, regardless of signal strength.

Comment: I've "genericized" the previous question's title to now read [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white/gray?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9642/981), and I think it adequately covers this.

Comment: @eldarerathis Oh, yeah that looks generic enough now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my stock Ice Cream Sandwich, the icons turn blue when there is Internet connectivity and grey when there isn't. I'm not sure on Gingerbread though.

Comment: Shouldn't the 3G icon not be there when there's no internet connectivity though?

Comment: It's not strictly "Internet" connectivity, it's connectivity to Google's services. The distinction is that you can be connected to the Internet but not to Google, feasibly. See [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white in Gingerbread?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9642/981)