# What does "H" mean in the signal indicator?

Tags: 3g, user-interface

I understand that the [colour of the signal indicator tells me whether or not I've got a connection to Google servers or not](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/what-does-it-mean-when-the-connectivity-icons-in-the-status-bar-go-white-gray), but what is the "H" that sometimes pops up?

[image: H]

Usually my indicator says "3G":

[image: 3G]

But, in addition to having an "H" now and again, sometimes it has no letters at all:

[image: nothing]

I assume this is telling something about what kind of data network I'm on, or not on, but what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's HSDPA which if I'm not mistaken is referring to 3.5G.

Comment: _and_ you're using Cyanogenmod -- plain old Android doesn't display an H, at least mine doesn't.

Comment: Actually, it does.  Seems to depend on version.

Comment: @offby1 From my experience I have seen H since the first day I bought my first Android device, which was HTC Hero GSM.

Comment: To be accurate, it means [HSPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Speed_Packet_Access), which includes HSDPA (download) and HSUPA (upload). Also, if there is no letter, it means there's no data connection or it's trying to connect to one.

Comment: or you're  on wifi.

Answer (score 28):

Let's state all the possible letters in the signal indicator, in descending speed (indicated speeds are roughly theoretical maximum):

- **5G** = 20 Gbps
- **LTE+** = 300 Mbps
- **LTE** = Long Term Evolution (commonly and falsely known as 4G), 100 Mbps
- **H+** = HSDPA Plus, 10 Mbps
- **H** = either HSDPA (3.5G) or HSPA+ (3.95G), depending on your network provider, 2 Mbps
- **3G** = UMTS (3G), 384 kbps
- **E** = EDGE (2.5G), 40 kbps
- **G** = GPRS (2G), 14 kbps
- (no letter) = voice only, no data connection, 2.4 kbps

*and also:*

- **R** = roaming (this means you're not on your home network)

([source](http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/Blog/G-H-E-3G-and-LTE-Making-sense-of-cell-network-alphabet-soup/ba-p/10735263) for some of this.)

Comment: There's also "4G" on my Nexus 5 running Lollipop (Optus, Australia).

Comment: My HTC One M7 also displays, 4G. I'm not sure if its LTE?

Comment: Can you expand on why LTE is "falsely known as 4G"? Other sources I've seen indicate that these are synonymous terms, so an explanation of your contrasting position could be informative.

Comment: @DanHenderson - "4G" is a marketing term, LTE is what it's actually called.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying you're wrong, but it's odd that you don't make any such distinction for 2G, 2.5G, 3G, 3.5G, 3.95G, nor 5G. Is "4G" the only "G" that's a misnomer? Also, the one source that you cited directly contradicts your position. **"4G, aka LTE - Long Term Evolution** *4G, also known as LTE, offers speeds of up to..."*