# Notification icon that looks like "no entry" symbol

Tags: notification-icons

There is an icon in my notification bar that looks like a [no entry symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcDfG.png) (far left):

[image: HTC android notification]

Does anyone know what it is/means? I have been unable to find out.

Comment: yeah looks like do not disturb. thanks a lot guys. I'm trying to post the actual pic but my email is messed up, can't get the pic from my phone to laptop

Comment: Please see [this page](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 4):

You've your phone on Total Silence (one of Do not Disturb modes).

In the section *Turn sounds back on (turn off "Do not disturb")* of the article [Silence your device with "Do not disturb"](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295?hl=en), Elena notes:

> If your phone is in "Do not disturb" mode, you'll see an icon in the status bar at the top of your screen:
>
> [image] Alarms only or Priority only
>
> [image] Total silence

Here's further proof:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Next time when you're in a similar situation, try these simple techniques I listed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/130102/96277).