# What does it mean when Wi-Fi icon is gray?

Tags: wi-fi

What does it mean when Wi-Fi icon is gray?

Internet is working at the moment.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: also [What does a grey Wi-Fi icon mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37698)

Answer (score 0):

It means that your Android device is not connected to the Google Servers. Because of this, your device can't receive any push notifications such a Gmail messages.