# ICS Wifi not blue and internet not working

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi

I just bought a Phone here yesterday running with Android ICS, the first time I used the wifi was ok, no problem. But now, the wifi is not working sometimes even I have a strong wifi connection. My PC, and my phone are on the same network. My PC is reading Full signal strength, as I am literally 5 feet from the wireless router. My phone is showing NO blue. Wifi meter is grey even if I have excellent connection, If it is blue, I can use my internet, but when it is grey I can't use my internet. I have the blue wifi around 20% of the time. What should I do?

Comment: See also: [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white/gray?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/16575) -- though that does not explain why your Internet should be completely disabled. Only Google Services have no connection, while everything else should be fine.

Comment: Have you tried restarting everything (router, phone)? Are you sure your router has enough available IP address and doesn't have a QoS rule blocking access? Can you connect to any other WiFi network? Are you sure you're connecting to the correct SSID?

Answer (score -1):

Exchange the phone for replacement.
Most likely defective wifi card in phone.

Comment: That's a pretty big leap without knowing if the OP has done any basic troubleshooting.

Answer (score -2):

wifi not blue means net cannot connect with google server! if u have rooted ur device just go to etc>hosts.bak using root explorer just add a '#' before the ip at the bottom line. Hope this will resolve ur issue works 99% with evry1! or try that on the first line ip!