# Why I Can't Use Wifi for anything except whatsapp?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I can't use WiFi for anything except WhatsApp on my *Samsung Galaxy S3 mini.*

I already turned on WiFi on my phone. But I can't do anything except WhatsApp. I can't browsing via WiFi, and can't open *Play Store* either. But when I use mobile data (via my Internet provider) I can do anything, except that I can't browse *Play Store* either.

When I use WiFi via my computer it can work, but can't work again via my phone.

The password is correct. I already check it, but nothing's work.

What should I do? Please help me!

Comment: Are there any error messages shown? Have you tried different WiFi networks? What confuses me is that you write WhatsApp is working. Are you sure about that, and is it really usind WiFi? As for the *Play Store* issue: what colors do your connection icons in the status bar have (blue or gray – see [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white/gray?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9642/16575))?

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue. Fixed it:

Set the router to automatically assign DNS.
Turn off PC, Router, Android.
Turn on PC, Router, Android after 15 sec.

Everything works like before now! :)

Comment: As for Wi-Fi, in order to change DNS you don't need root nor that app. All you need is go to wifi settings, long-tap on a wifi connection>modify network>show advanced options>IP Settings, there you can put any DNS you wish :) but that couldn't be a good solution for above problem, because that error had some specific manner

Comment: Ilo: I'd say that's a great solution if the reason WhatsApp is the only app working is that it uses IP-addresses and not DNS, making the primary issue a DNS issue :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me 100%. Go to WiFi settings in your phone. Long tap the connected WiFi connection, select *modify network settings* and check if proxy is enabled which I am sure will be **enabled**, just switch it back to **NONE**, then again switch off the WiFi and switch it on again. Viola, the internet is back again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when changed my router from 3com to Asus DSL-N12E_C1 .
my DNS was set to automatic by default . I only changed it to google DNS :
8.8.8.8 and it amazingly WORKED .

Answer (score -2):

Clean all the cache using [All-In-One Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.toolbox.full), and restart your phone. It worked for me.