# With Android 4.4 (KitKat), my notification icons are always gray. Am I in trouble?

Tags: data-connection, notification-icons, 4.4-kitkat

With Android 4.3 and earlier, gray/white signal icons in the notification bar informed about connection trouble concerning the Google Services (see e.g. [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white/gray?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9642/16575)). If everything was OK, they were either green (before 4.x) or blue (4.0+). Now they seem to be permanently gray/white. Am I in trouble, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are (not) in trouble. Or at least you cannot tell anymore by simply taking a look at the notification bar. With Android 4.4 (KitKat) came a few design changes; one of them was to turn those notification icons permanently gray, officially to be "less distracting".

So how can you tell if there are issues with your connection to the Google servers? According to an [AndroidPIT Blog](http://www.androidpit.de/android-4-4-design-aenderungen-ueberblick#comment659636), you now have to check with the Quick-Settings, where problems are indicated by icons turned red/orange.

Comment: I think the icons show in orange rather than red but other than that you're correct.

Comment: I have not yet seen them, so my information is rather "2nd hand". But it could also be a question of shade: some report their icons are "permanently gray", while others speak of white. Thanks for the feedback, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have a dual-chip Moto G running kitkat (4.4.2), upgraded today. On a certain wifi that would be always gray up to ICS, now the notification bar shows wifi and GSM1 gray and GSM2 orange (although mobile data is disabled on both), and if I open quicksettings, everything is orange! Why is so?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy maybe you make that a separate question, that's quite a bit specific (and I don't know to tell)?