# Android WIFI grey/blue icon (and performance) depends on AP?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, notification-icons

I have a very *peculiar* issue with my Android Tablet.

Issue: 
Tablet has good access to Internet and blue icon whenn connected to AP (access point) "A", poor access and grey icon with AP "B"

Hardware: 
Ramos i9 Android 4.2.2. 
Router/WIFI AP Zyxel P-2812HNU-F3 ("B" above)
Apple AirPort ("A" above)

Description:
I have the i9 since 2 weeks. After working flawlessy, since two days I notice a degraded internet performance. Tunein radios do not connect, internet page are slow etc and WIFI ICON IS GREY. The connectivty is not completely absent, it is just "slow".

With my surprise, my Huawei Y300 and other HW (iMac, iPod etc) all is working fine with my Zyxel. I did a try and turned my Huawei to WIFI Hotspot and connecting the i9 to this new WIFI, ALSO my i9 works nicely! (BLUE ICON etc etc)

I then connect my (old) AirPort to the LAN of the Zyxel, and configure teh Airport as a new WIFI. Surprise! If I connect the i9 to the AirPort all works! Notice the Airport has NO access to internet! The Airport has to go through the Zyxel!

Give the above I assume is something related to the "radio transmission" area. I then changed transmission channel and lowered transmission standard (from b/g/n to b/g) of my Zyxel, but still no result ...

Any idea? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Related: [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white/gray?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9642/16575) / [With Android 4.4 (KitKat), my notification icons are always gray. Am I in trouble?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57003/16575) Maybe that helps you in analysis. Maybe your ZyXEL itself has a poor internet connection?