# How to troubleshoot wifi connection problem?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, networking, troubleshooting

Like some other people, I am plagued by the [issue with gray wifi bars](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57402/how-to-fix-grey-wifi-icon-no-internet-and-how-to-track-what-caused-that) with a tablet running 4.2.2. I tried all recommended solutions: disabling power saving, switching between AES/TKIP on the router, making sure the clock was set correctly, etc. As you can well guess, nothing works

When I connect to the router, the bars are usually grey and I cannot connect to the Internet OR any local machine, including the router's web interface. After several minutes, the bars sometimes go blue, and sometimes don't. After they go blue, they can also go back to grey from time to time.

Obviously, this has something to do with the router because if I reset it, I can usually connect without a problem. But after a while, the bars go to gray again. The router has no filtering configured and all other devices (including several Android phones) have no problems connecting to and accessing the network.

The question is not about solving this problem, but rather about any ways of troubleshooting this issue. Is there a simple way I can get a shell, try pinging some hosts, get a look at ifconfig, anything? Are there some system logs that could show what is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a linux system on a pc or laptop to troubleshoot this wifi connection, using ifconfig, ping, iwconfig. There are also nice dhcp tools on linux.

When I had wifi connection problems on an Android phone, with a linux system I found the error in the dhcp server setup. After fixing this, the Android phone connected effortless.

Comment: All that is rather obvious, question is how to get access to the shell/logs on the Android device. It isn't helpful to debug the issue from a PC, since there's nothing to debug - all other devices connect without a problem.