# Wifi not working too well.. :c

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

On my Android Gingerbread device (keep in mind that it is the pratically extinct Walkman, which is basically Android's attempt at a iPod) my wifi keeps on going white, and when it happens I can't use Text+ and stuff like that. I have no idea why, but it keeps on doing that. When its green though, it lets me go on it. It toggles from normal connection to only games, basically. Anyone know why my wifi won't work?

Comment: The color-change you describe has to do with connection to Google servers (see: [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white/gray?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9642/16575)). So the problem might not even be on your end: it could well be some routing stuff, or Google having trouble on their end.

Answer (score 1):

When it's white, it means that Android can connect to the Wi-Fi access point but cannot get a connection to the Internet (more specifically, it is [trying to connect to one of Google's server if you have Google Account registered in the device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/what-does-it-mean-when-the-connectivity-icons-in-the-status-bar-go-white-gray)). This may happen if you connect to an open Wi-Fi access point that requires sign-in through the browser or which provides only local access or if your device is incorrectly connected to such access points (sometimes devices are configured to automatically connect to any open Wi-Fi access point or to any access points it has once connected to).

When this happens, check that you're connected to the correct access point; ensure that your device is not set to automatically connect to open Wi-Fi access point; and to set the device to forget the incorrectly connected access point so it wouldn't try to reconnect there in the future.