# Cannot download anything from Google Play store via mobile data

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, updates, mobile-data

I have an LG G2 with Android 4.4.2. All of a sudden I cannot download apps or updates on the Google Play store: no error messages, it just spins its wheels. On the Google Play Store, it just says "Downloading..." with the loading bar running infinitely, and in my phone drop-down screen, the same thing. No progress bar, completion %, est. time, anything.

In my *Settings › Mobile data* menu, the "limit mobile data usage" option is NOT checked, and the problem persists on both 3G and 4G/LTE. My data limit has not been reached (I don't even think I have one).

In the *Settings › Mobile data › Google Play Store* menu, the "restrict background data" option is NOT checked either. In the *Google Play* app settings menu, the "Auto-update apps" is set to wifi-only, but that's how I want it. The problem is when I manually try to download/update, so that shouldn't be the problem.

My Google Play build version is 5.4.12, if that helps...

Wi-fi downloads are just peachy though.

**Just checked my network signal strength and it's -116 dBm and 26 asu, whatever those mean.**

Comment: I've integrated that with your question directly, thanks for the feedback! One more thing: while "the wheel spins", what color does your mobile-signal-icon show (in 4.4+, this "color change" was IMHO moved into the quick-settings – so you might need to pull down your notification bar and check the "tiles" – before that, it was visible directly in the status bar)?

Comment: No colors change anywhere- they remain white/gray like the default. Though by "mobile-signal-icon," do you mean the staircase bars or the icon for 3G/4G/LTE? Nothing in my Quick Settings changed at all.

Comment: Tried clearing data for Play Services and Play Store?

Comment: @Willman42 Take a look at [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white/gray?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9642/16575) for what I mean. Color meanings for gray/white stay the same with 4.4+ – so your device has no connection to the Google Servers. Explains the issue, right? While on WiFi, WiFi icon color is different I guess?

Comment: @Huey doesn't help. Icons indicate "no connection to Google servers".

Comment: Is it possible your internet connection is somehow malfunctioning? Can you visit [http://google.com](http://www.google.com) and [play.google.com](http://play.google.com) in your web browser?

Comment: @Huey - this problem occurs no matter what network I'm on; I can access Play Store from browser, and phone on wifi AND mobile data.

Comment: @Izzy - My icons (data,wifi,anything) haven't been anything buy white/grey for a LONG time now (they were green when I bought the phone). I can't remember for certain, but I'm pretty sure they turned white when I got an Android update long ago, perhaps a year or so. I don't remember ever changing my Google Acct settings after initially adding it. I'll check out my acct settings now and see if I can nudge something to get it green again though.

Comment: @Izzy - http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/18/a-google-engineer-explains-why-kitkat-has-white-status-bar-icons-and-only-shows-connectivity-in-quick-settings/ This page states that "A blue WiFi or mobile data icon meant connected, and gray was no connectivity. But no more. ... In KitKat, the status icons are white all the time."

Comment: @Willman42 Yes, that's what I wrote: from Kitkat upwards, the status icons ***in the statusbar*** always remain white. I cannot cross-check currently (no device beyond 4.3), but AFAIK now colors are changed ***in the quick settings***. We had that in some answer here, I just couldn't find it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I let an update attempt to download then came back to my phone about 10-15 min later, to see an error code 495, saying the update cannot download. So I Googled that error code and found this page: http://techknowzone.com/how-to-solve-fix-error-code-495-in-google-play-store/. I went down the list and followed each suggestion step by step.

**The one that worked was disconnecting and reconnecting my Google acct from my phone.** I had to reboot my device because it seems like whenever I clear the cache/data from Google Play Store and Google Framework Service and then open up Google Play store again, it says "unable to connect" no matter how many times I click "retry."

So I don't know exactly what was wrong- it seems like it's just a bug buried deep somewhere. But it works now. Network icons are still white.

Answer (score 3):

Open downloads app or download manager.  Change the setting of the max size of file you can download using mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your account from Google play store.
2. Go to Settings > Apps > *Clear data* and *Clear cache* on Play store , Play services, Google Service framework and Download manager.
3. Reset App preferences in Settings > Apps
4. Switch on your location in GPS of your mobile.
5. Reboot your mobile.

Now you can download from your play store.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the *Restrict background data* option Settings → App → Downloads (might have been enabled). Try downloading the App in Play store again.