# unable to download from google play store

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

My device is micromax nitro 2..downloading over mobile data has become impossible ..when I try to download from playstore,it shows infinite downloading. Even to download a 1 mb app.I have another device in possession,which is Gionee pioneer p1..By tethering internet from micromax,the internet acess and downloading has been super fast in it..So is my micromax device experiencing any problem or can it be solved???

Comment: What is the free space left in your Micromax Nitro 2? Clear cache and data for Google Play services and try again by rebooting the device.

Comment: I got 2 gb internal memory and 1.46 gb Ram as free space

Comment: Do you get any popup messages after the download starts?  Clear cache/data of the Download manager in the All apps under Settings menu and try.

Comment: Hey, the after clearing cache of download manager, the downloading app showed in notification bar...but after a few minutes, it showed (error downloading 495)

Comment: Now clear the Cache/Data of the Google Play Store and try. Check [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23055/what-is-error-code-495-on-google-play-and-the-youtube-app) for the error 495 you are getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot download anything from Google Play store via mobile data](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/107103/cannot-download-anything-from-google-play-store-via-mobile-data)

Answer (score 0):

Clean Google Play Store cache, force stop it and reboot your device if it doesn't work clean data from play store and add new google account

Comment: What do you mean by a new google account? By the way,I have tried everything else you recommended

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue and i have gone through several forums for the help.All have suggested the same .

> Clear cache and clear data of the playstore.
>   Force stop the playstore.
>   Remove and add google account.

I have tried all of the above but not found any good.

But after lot of trail and error i have resolved the issue.

Solution is the same as above but the sequence order is very important.

Please follow the exact order given below.

1). Google Playstore - Go to Settings >> Apps>> 'All' tab >> Select Google Playstore - Now Uninstall all updates >>Force stop >> Clear Cache>> Clear Data.
2). Download Manager - Go to Settings >> Apps>> 'All' tab >> Select Download Manager - Force stop >> Clear Cache>> Clear Data.
3). Downloads - Go to Settings >> Apps>> 'All' tab >> Select Downloads - Force stop if the button is active.
4). Remove the google account.
5). Restart the device.
6). Add Google account.

(Assuming you have followed the sequence properly)

In case the above steps don't resolve the issue and you are using Mobile data then follow the below steps

1 > Check your storage space in your phone and ensure required space is available.
2 > Please go to Settings >> Mobile Networks >>Access point Names /APN >> Go to APN Protocol Change it to IPV6 and APN Roaming Protocol to 'IPV4/Ipv6'.

Thats all !!! -  Enjoy , Don't forget to vote for the reply